# Can't get proxy working in create-react-app/webpack

Tags: webpack, proxy, xampp, fetch, create-react-app

I'm trying to set up a `localhost` dev server for a react app made using `create-react-app`. Part of the app makes some simple `fetch` requests to PHP files for retrieving and updating data (using SleekDB).

The `build` version made via `npm run build` works fine on the deployment server, but as it's a pain running `npm run build` everytime I change a PHP file I'm trying to set up a local server.

I've installed XAMPP, set the `documentRoot` and using `localhost:80/php/getTasks.php` works like a charm. The hair-pulling is coming from trying to get the react dev server on `localhost:3000` to make proxy calls to `localhost:80`. The following function is calling 3000, not 80, and so is returning the contents of the PHP script.

**Fetch request in react**

```
        const fetchTasks = async () => {
            const res = await fetch("php/getTasks.php", {
                method: "GET",
                mode: "cors",
                headers: {"Content-type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"}
            })
            console.log(await res.text())
            // return await res.json();
        }
        await fetchTasks();
        // const tasksFromServer = await fetchTasks()
        // console.log(tasksFromServer)
        // setTasks(tasksFromServer.map((x, i) => x.id ? x : {...x, id: i + 1}))
    }
```

**getTasks.php**
*Works if called directly at `http://localhost:80/php/getTasks.php`*

```
require_once("./dbInit.php");
echo json_encode($tasksStore->findAll());
```

This is a common topic and I've spent hours going through dozens of posts with no luck. So far I've tried:

- Adding `"proxy": "http://localhost:80/public"` to my `package.json` file as per the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development)
- Adding a more detailed `devServer` object into `webpack.config.js` (below)
- Adding a more detailed `proxy` object into `webpackDevServer.config.js` (below)
- Adding `method: "GET", mode: "cors",headers: {"Content-type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"` to the `GET` request
- Various paths in the configs

So far the only thing that works is changing the `fetch` URL to an absolute `http://localhost:80/public/php/getTasks.php`, which is going to make compiling a pain

I must be missing something really obvious but this level of development is new to me and I'm struggling to see what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me?

**webpack.config.json**
*Inserted at top-level of exports()*

```
            historyApiFallBack: true,
            // progress: true,
            hot: true,
            inline: true,
            // https: true,
            port: 3000,
            // contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
            proxy: {
                '/php/': {
                    target: 'http://localhost:80/public/php',
                    secure: false,
                    changeOrigin: true
                },
                'php/*': {
                    target: 'http://localhost:80/public/php',
                    secure: false,
                    changeOrigin: true
                },
                'php/': {
                    target: 'http://localhost:80/public/php',
                    secure: false,
                    changeOrigin: true
                },
                '/php/*': {
                    target: 'http://localhost:80/public/php',
                    secure: false,
                    changeOrigin: true
                },
                'http://localhost:3000/php/*': {
                    target: 'http://localhost:80/public/php',
                    secure: false,
                    changeOrigin: true
                },
                'http://localhost:3000/php/': {
                    target: 'http://localhost:80/public/php',
                    secure: false,
                    changeOrigin: true
                }
            }
```

**webpackDevServer.config.js**
*Replaces `proxy`*

```
// `proxy` is run between `before` and `after` `webpack-dev-server` hooks
    proxy: {
      '/php': {
        target: 'http://localhost:80/public',
        pathRewrite: {'/php': 'http://localhost:80/public/public/php'},
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        ws: true
      },
      './php': {
        target: 'http://localhost:80/public',
        pathRewrite: {'/php': 'http://localhost:80/public/public/php'},
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        ws: true

      },
      'php': {
        target: 'http://localhost:80/public',
        pathRewrite: {'/php': 'http://localhost:80/public/public/php'},
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        ws: true
      },
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Methods, Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST",
      },
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out by following the steps in this [article](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/react-how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-5588a9e0347).

**Tl;dr**

Run `npm install http-proxy-middleware --save`

In `create-react-app` `src` folder create a file `setupProxy.js`

In `setupProxy.js` add the following code, changing `'/php`, `'http://localhost:80` and the `pathRewrite` parts to match your project

**setupProxy.js**

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(
        '/php',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'http://localhost:80',
            changeOrigin: true,
            secure: false,
            pathRewrite: {
                '^/php': '/public/php'
            }
        })
    );
};
```